# How to build a query to count all users who signed up after me?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am developing an MLM application using PHP & MySQL. I am facing some difficulties in a MySQL query.

Here is the link to [sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d1b7a/3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d1b7a/3)

My table structure is like this:

[image]

I want to select all the records from the table and count the number of members joined after a member. And the count is based on the `created_on` field. My proposed output is like:

[image]

The calculation of `total_under_me` is wrong.

I used this query: `select * from users group by id`

Comment: Maybe http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d1b7a/9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use subquery like this:

```
select t1.*, (select count(t2.`id`) from `users` as t2 where t2.`created_on` > t1.`created_on`) as `after_this` from users as t1
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to count the total number of users where `created_on` is greater than the value of `created_on` for the user in question.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_under_me from users
WHERE created_on > 
(SELECT created_on FROM users WHERE first_name ='Admin')
```

In my example above, I am counting the number of users who joined after the user with the first name of Admin.

Comment: Dear, you miss understood my issue. Thanks for the help.